# classpath wildcard in @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, config

I am using Spring Java config to create my bean.
But this bean is common to 2 applications.
Both have one property file abc.properties but with different classpath locations.
When i put explicit classpath like

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/app1/abc.properties")
```

then it works but when i try to use wildcard like

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/**/abc.properties")
```

then it doesn't work.
I try many combinations of wildcard but it still not working.
Is wildcard works in `@ProeprtySource`
Is there any other way to read to property in classed marked with `@Configurations`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@PropertySource API: `Resource location wildcards (e.g. **/*.properties) are not permitted; each location must evaluate to exactly one .properties resource.`

workaround: try

```
@Configuration
public class Test {

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer()
            throws IOException {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/**/abc.properties"));
        return ppc;
    }
```

Comment: Adding `static` modifier will prevent warning given while deployment: "ConfigurationClassEnhancer:310 - `@Bean` method Test.getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as `@Autowired`, `@Resource` and `@PostConstruct` within the method's declaring `@Configuration` class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see `@Bean` javadoc for complete details."
But Thanks, this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

Addidtionally to **dmay** workaround:

Since Spring 3.1 PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer should be used preferentially over PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and the bean should be static.

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/**/abc.properties"));
    return propertyConfigurer;
  }

}
```

Comment: There is an essential problem with this solution: The precedence of properties imported by `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#setLocations` is even higher than system properties. So you cannot use system properties or command line arguments to override them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YAML properties, this can be achieved using a custom `PropertySourceFactory`:

```java
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YamlPropertySourceFactory.class);

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(
            @Nullable String name,
            @NonNull EncodedResource encodedResource
    ) {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        String path = ((ClassPathResource) encodedResource.getResource()).getPath();
        String filename = encodedResource.getResource().getFilename();
        Properties properties;
        try {
            factory.setResources(
                    new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(path)
            );
            properties = Optional.ofNullable(factory.getObject()).orElseGet(Properties::new);
            return new PropertiesPropertySource(filename, properties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Properties not configured correctly for {}", path, e);
            return new PropertiesPropertySource(filename, new Properties());
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:**/props.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    // ...
}
```