# Spring Java Config: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's "locations" equivalent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application where i wan't to inject properties. In our previous projects we defined a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in our `context.xml` to load the property files from all dependent modules at once:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:/META-INF/*.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now I am looking for a worthy alternative in Java config style. I tried to annotate my configuration class as follows:

```
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath*:/META-INF/*.properties") })
```

But the `@PropertySource` annotation doesn't like wildcards (which makes sense as it is responsible for fetching a single resource).

Any ideas, hints, solutions?

Comment: Note that a declared `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean and `@PropertySources` are not equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicte of [classpath-wildcard-in-propertysource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389995/classpath-wildcard-in-propertysource).

Answer (score -1):

Ya, this is awkward as `PropertySource` doesnt support wildcards. A reasonable solution has been offered up on a previous question and I've used it successfully.

[classpath wildcard in @PropertySource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389995/classpath-wildcard-in-propertysource)

Comment: You should just vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: ah, thanks Sotirios, I'll remember that in future.