# Spring boot configuration multi modules

Tags: spring-boot, module

According to some other posts, it looks only one `application.properties` in the top-level aggregator project should be defined.

Then, in other modules, a specific file by module for related properties handled using `@PropertyResource`.

**It looks wildcard on property resources are not supported or not handled when using spring boot?!**

Let's imagine we develop an engine application:

Modules: engine-core, engine-communication, engine-launcher (module containing the spring boot application).

In the engine launcher module, I would like to define a configuration like this:

`@Configuration 
@PropertySource(value = "classpath*:/config/engine-*-config.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) 
public class EngineConfiguration { ... }`

With related configuration files in the modules. When doing this, it looks these configuration files cannot be found.

What's the best way to have a modular/flexible configuration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks @PropertySource does not support wildcard for resource locations as explained in the following post: [classpath wildcard in @PropertySource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389995/classpath-wildcard-in-propertysource)